# Direction for deburring and filing tools

Tags: hand-tools

After cutting a metal block I need to deburr the corners and edges. If there a large edge that stands out, I like to use a file, rather than a small deburring tool.

However I never understood why the deburring tool needs to be operated towards me, while the file needs to be slid away from me. Why the discrepancy in the directions?

Comment: What deburring tool are you using?

Comment: @SpeedyPetey As far as I am aware there are only a few deburring tools available. You can learn more about them here, for example: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/68800/can-you-deburr-copper-pipes-with-a-fitting-brush

Comment: Thanks @FreshAir, I am aware of deburring tools. I asked which one he is using.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey & FreshAir The one I'm using is similar to this one - http://www.use-enco.com/ProductImages/0575229-23.jpg. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, when speaking of different types of files the cutting teeth on the grooves are oriented in different ways but are usually forward facing.  When pushed the teeth are able to cut the material properly.

Most novice users tend to adopt a sawing motion twice as many passes with the file, thinking it will take half the time to do the work. Unfortunately not.

If the file is employed this way with cutting happening on the forward stroke, the teeth will bend causing permanent damage on the draw stroke.

Best thing is to research any tools and procedures before starting the project.  And find the right tool for the job.